# convert key value pairs into array javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an object that I receive from html form, and it has the following syntax:

```
  'ingredients[0][name]': 'eggplant',
  'ingredients[0][mass]': '1',
  'ingredients[0][units]': 'pc',
  'ingredients[1][name]': 'cheese',
  'ingredients[1][mass]': '150',
  'ingredients[1][units]': 'gr',
  'ingredients[2][name]': 'cilantro',
  'ingredients[2][mass]': '100',
  'ingredients[2][units]': 'tt' ...
```

All that I need is to convert these key-value pairs into the one big object field. Such as

```
recipe = {
    ingredients: [
        {
            name: 'epplant',
            mass: '1',
            units: 'pc'
        },
        {
            name: 'cheese',
            mass: '150',
            units: 'gr'
        }, ...
    ]
}
```

How can I do this without JQuery or other JS-framework?

Comment: what type of object you recieve from the form.is it a javascript object?

Comment: yep, it is an JS object, like form = { key1: value1, key2: value2 } and so on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var form = {
  'ingredients[0][name]': 'eggplant',
  'ingredients[0][mass]': '1',
  'ingredients[0][units]': 'pc',
  'ingredients[1][name]': 'cheese',
  'ingredients[1][mass]': '150',
  'ingredients[1][units]': 'gr',
  'ingredients[2][name]': 'cilantro',
  'ingredients[2][mass]': '100',
  'ingredients[2][units]': 'tt'
}

var re = /([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z_0-9]*)\[(\d+)\]\[([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*)\]/

var result = {}

for (var key in form) {
    var match = key.match(re)
    if (!match) continue
    var arr = result[match[1]]
    if (!arr) arr = result[match[1]] = []
    var obj = arr[match[2]]
    if (!obj) obj = arr[match[2]] = {}
    obj[match[3]] = form[key]
}

console.log(result)
```

http://jsfiddle.net/r1gkog1b/

UPD: some explanation:

I think, you should iterate throw your input form object keys and parse its with regexp. In case of match you can construct desirable output structure

Comment: Please don't just post answers, but explain what they are doing.

Comment: Thanks, Alexey @Алексей-Овчинников ! That's a great idea, because I have other fields and need them to be converted into an JS Object fields. But I'm not sure about performance - I heard that regular expressions aren't fast.

Comment: regarding permormance - I think that there are only one way is to parse key with regexp (in case you need some unification) and my code have precompiled regexp so this is a faster possible way